# Items in SharePoint list missing under different access scenarios

Tags: custom-list, microsoft-access

I have a custom SharePoint list which is configured to hold two content types: folder (added automatically but never used) and item. List settings are pretty much default. Specifically, there is only the default view, and no workflow is associated with the list.

Users access this list through an Access database, into which it is linked as a table. The Access database itself is stored on the SharePoint site; some use local copies of the file as the logic never changes (only the data does, which is stored on the server anyway) and performance is much better with the local version.

However, I am having issues with some list items missing, resulting in aggregate functions returning incorrect results. The behavior seems completely random: my colleague is seeing all items when opening the .accdb from the server, but some are missing when he uses a local copy. For me, it is the other way round—the local copy sees all items but the server version is missing some.

As the DB is used for budget planning, missing items mean the whole DB can no longer be trusted and relied upon for planning.

What could be the cause of these missing items, especially the seemingly random behavior I’m seeing?